How to tell the compiler a function argument will never be zero?
Imagine I have a dummy C function like this:
void Dummy(uint64* dest, const size_t count)
{
  for (size_t ii = 0; ii < count; ii += 8) {
    *dest++ = (uint64)dest;
  }
}

If you look at what the compiler creates, the first instruction will check that the value of count is not zero.
Dummy(unsigned long*, unsigned long):
        cbz     x1, .LBB0_7
        ...
.LBB0_7:
        ret


Is there an attribute I can place on count to indicate that this value is guaranteed to never be zero and this unnecessary comparison can be omitted?  Is there another coding-style that I could deploy?
Changing the for loop to a while loop and other forms doesn't seem to matter. Compilers are clever!
And, yes, I do care about this single tiny little instruction.

C or C++? These are very different languages. C++ might have some way to do this, C almost certainly doesn't.

There's no way I know of to tell the compiler to make an assumption like this.  And what happens if the assumption turns out to be wrong?

@MarkRansom UB, obviously.

@Barmar and maybe therein lies the solution.  If you create a situation where UB is invoked early when the parameter is zero, the compiler will be able to deduce that it can't be zero.

@MarkRansom And in this example, nothing bad. The check is just an optimization to skip over initializing ii and testing that. If it's wrong, it will be slightly less efficient.

Ah, so start the function with (void)(1/count);.

C++23 has [[assume]] attribute exactly for that. Though I don't know if it's already implemented reasonably in compilers

@Yksisarvinen: As you might see in external links, clang/gcc/msvc have already their own attribute for that

@lanceLanceE.T.Compte,
Does void Dummy(const size_t count, uint64 dest[count]) in C help?

Sadly there is no way of reliably declaring information like that. You can use attributes and HOPE that they are not ignored, or you can write a statement that would result in UB and (again) hope that the compiler uses that information.

Your question is too broad since answers in C and C++ will be different here. Please post 2 separate questions per language if you are interested in answers for each language.

Other than that, switching for for do while would move the comparison after the loop body so that way we could skip the first comparison vs zero.

@Lundin, I was puzzled why you asked for more clarity on my question. I removed the [c++] tag. Thanks.

GCC has attribute assume for that:
void Dummy(uint64_t* dest, const size_t count)
{
    __attribute__((assume(count != 0)));
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < count; ii += 8) 
    {
        *dest++ = (uint64_t)dest;
    }
}

And the check disappears.

assume is standard since C++23. https://godbolt.org/z/EvovPPre1

@FrançoisAndrieux not everyone can use C++23 in projects.

Put the expression 1/count somewhere in the function. Division by zero causes undefined behavior. Since the compiler is allowed to assume UB never occurs, this implies count can't be zero.

Thanks @Barmar. That's clever, but I'm choosing the other approach. It just seems a little cleaner.

Of course, although that solution is compiler-specific. This should theoretically work with any sufficiently smart optimizer.

Actually @Barmar, the compiler I must use doesn't seem to support the attribute, so I'm using your  approach with a huge comment block that explains what I'm doing.

Standard way is using attribute [[assume(expression)]](C++23):
void Dummy(std::uint64_t* dest, const std::size_t count)
{
    [[assume(count != 0)]];

    for (std::size_t ii = 0; ii < count; ii += 8) {
        *dest++ = (uint64_t)dest;
    }
}

The standard way is to standardize already existing extensions:

__builtin_assume (clang)
__assume (MSVC)
__attribute__((assume(...))) (gcc)


Changing the for loop to a while loop and other forms doesn't seem to matter. Compilers are CLEVER!

Following code gives similar result, without assume and with do .. while:
void Dummy(std::uint64_t* dest, const std::size_t count)
{
    std::size_t ii = 0;
    do {
        *dest++ = (uint64_t)dest;
        ii += 8;
    } while (ii < count);
}

Demo
